# 10 people, 2 groups with equally summed ages

Tags: combinatorics

> In a room there are 10 people, none of them is younger than 1 or older than 100 years. Prove
>   that among them, one can always find two groups of people (possibly intersecting, but different)
>   the sums of whose ages are the same.
>
> Hint: Use the pigeonhole principle. How many different groups of
>   people can be picked? How large the sum of their ages can be?

I don't know where to begin. My professor tackled a similar question to this in class, but he used a diagram with a smaller amount of people (6) and did not solve it combinatorically. I also began this problem assuming it meant pairs of people, but from what I can see it can include a group of any size (excluding one..right? I mean a group of one wouldn't have a sum).

If someone could help destruct this with me, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Your "possibly intersecting" is unnecessary (not to say confusing). If two such groups intersect, we can just remove the people common to them both, and the sum of the ages in the resulting groups will still be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpacking this a little more:

For a particular selection of group from the $10$ people, each person is either in that group or not, so you can specify any group by stating "in" or "out" for each person of the $10$. To generate all groups you multiply all those "in-out" binary decisions across all the people: $2^{10}=1024$. One of the results is the empty group, and one is the group of all $10$ people, which are not relevant to the problem at hand, so we can consider the space of $1022$ selected groups (ranging in size from $1$ to $9$ people).

Now the maximum possible group age total is $900$ and the minimum is $1$, giving $900$ different possible age totals, so by the pigeonhole principle there must be at least two possible groups with the same age total, which answers the given question.

We can push the result a little further. Note that there are only 10 groups with 9 members, but if we exclude them then the maximum possible total drops significantly: $1012$ possible groups across the range of age totals from $1$ to $800$. Similarly we can successively exclude groups of size $8$, $7$ and $6$. This leaves :
$$\sum_{k=1}^5 {10 \choose k}=637$$ 
possible groups of sizes $1$ to $5$ with $500$ as the maximum age total, so again the pigeonhole principle tells us that there will at least $2$ groups with the same age total. Furthermore we can drop the size $1$ and $2$ groups from consideration and still have enough possible ways of choosing groups of size $3$ to $5$ - $582$ - to ensure that two of those groups have the same age total.

Comment: Thanks for revisiting this - I actually had follow up questions and you clarified a lot of them

Comment: Are there any possible sets of $10$ people where the groups _need_ five or more people each?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I did consider that very thing... I can get close to restricting consideration to groups up to size $4$ but I can't quite make it happen.

Answer (score 4):

There are $2^{10} - 1 = 1023$ groups we can form (or one less if we discount the total group).

The maximal sum is $10 \cdot 100 = 1000$, the minimal one $1 \cdot 1$. So at most 1000 different sums.

Comment: Neat!  And we can even toss out the groups with one member and it still works.

Comment: We can actually guarantee finding two such groups with between 3 and 5 people in.

Comment: Thank you for this! If you don't mind, could you walk me through how you concluded that the answer was 2^10 - 1 (assuming we include the total group)? I'm sorry for coming off obtuse but I'm not quite grasping how you came to your answer.

Comment: Thank you for unpacking that for me, it makes sense now :)